# Apple WatchOS publish/broadcast Heartrate service using Bluetooth, How to?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, unreal-engine4, watchos

I want to build a watch os app that reads heart rate and broadcasts it as a service using Bluetooth BLE, Is this possible?

Additional maybe useful info: I will try to listen to this service from an Unreal game on iOS.

Edit: I tried building a watch companion app that sends heart rate using WatchConnectivity but I could not build the unreal game with the Watch companion. so I am looking into the Bluetooth option.

Comment: What kind of research did you do? What makes you believe this is not possible?

Comment: I think it is possible but I don't know how or what steps to do.
I tried building a watch companion app that sends heart rate using WatchConnectivity but I can't add the watch to the unreal engine xcode project.
so I am looking into other options like building an independant WatchOS app and see if I can connect to it using bluetooth.